# What would cause a : current database instance is not active [Orientdb][SPARK]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, orientdb

I am running a spark(2.3.4) application to populate an orientdb (3.0.34) database.

**Configs:**
spark : local[*]

**OrientDB**

```
         this.context = new OrientDB(remoteConnexionCommand, dbUser, dbPwd, dbConfig)
         this.pool = new ODatabasePool(this.context, globalConfig.getString("db.name"), dbUser, dbPwd)
```

Then at some point I try to do an upsert on some edge and the error popup:

```
   The current database instance (com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseDocumentRemotePooled@737aa62f) is not active on the current thread (Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 319,5,main]). Current active database is: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseDocumentRemotePooled@265d0416
```

I couldn't put all of the code here for this issue, but one starting point for me to try to solve it, is to understand what would cause this error, and also how to reproduce it, **it seems to happen in an unpredicted manner**.

Also I noticed that the object pool is created twice in the application, not sure why, but would it be the cause ?

**EDIT**

Code to create a connection to db is executed inside a rdd.foreach method as described here:

```
rdd.repartition(20).foreach(row => {
        try {
          DBManager session = DBManager.getSession() // which init a new Session given an initialized pool
          session.command(statement, params)
        } catch {
          case t: Throwable => ...
        }
```

Therefore the code that initializes the dbConnection is done in the worker nodes.

Comment: Sounds like DB connection is created on driver node and reused from worker nodes. DB connection should be created on each worker node.

Comment: it happens that the stacktrace get us inside a rdd.foreach which initializes a new session therefore the db connection seems to be created on the workers. I was wondering if foreachPartitions would have any advantage regarding this problem.

Comment: Is the pool also being created on each worker?

Comment: The pool is created once at the begining of the app, and reused each time we create a session. at the db. Typically the getSession does : if(pool == null) new Exception else new Session(pool.acquire)

Comment: Then it means you create a pool on the master node and try to use that pool from driver nodes, right? This can't work. Each worker node need its own pool.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications, so that shared pool would be the root cause. Could you elaborate more on what happens under the hood and leads that the current thread taking a bad pool reference and that it happens unpredictably ? If you have any assumptions.

Comment: Also the right question to ask maybe is what's wrong with creating a connection pool and pass it to an action executed by the worker

Comment: Can't say with certitude or precise details but anything that opens/manages resources (connections to the DB here) cannot be shared between nodes because it's somehow tied to the original JVM/node.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, I'll try to dig more into it, and try to understand why the issue seems to happen once or twice a week for a daily job and then works fine.